# How Can I Pass a String From Applescript to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I'm working on an application where I need to be able to **pass a string variable** from **Applescript** to **Objective C**. I have figured out how to run Applescript from a method in my Objective C Class, but I need to be able to **set an NSString to a string from Applescript**. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick example:

```
NSString *theScript =   @"set theTimeString to time string of (current date)\n"
                         "return theTimeString";

NSDictionary *errorInfo = nil;
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:theScript];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *theDescriptor = [run executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
NSString *theResult = [theDescriptor stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@",theResult);
```

Output:

> 2:36:06 PM

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for NSAppleEventDescriptor, especially the method [-[NSAppleEventDescriptor stringValue]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleEventDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleEventDescriptor/stringValue)